# How could some html buttons in web sites, do things without calling JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, get

In [this dictionary web site](http://maduraonline.com/), there is an HTML button labeled **"Translate"** which translates the word inside the textbox into Sinhala language.  The translate button doesn't call a function which exists within the scoop, but the translation is performed. What action does the button trigger? How is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: It submits a form and reloads the page, which is what a submit button is supposed to do ?

Comment: The form input is passed via `GET` to a PHP page, and it then processes and outputs the result in a ***different*** page. It has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: the form `action="/"` and its `method="get"` with a submit button and the rest is php work ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a basic form.  the Translate button submits the form, the page refreshes and the result is shown on the page. we cannot tell what action is performed because we wouldnt have access to the server side code that does the processing

view the source of the page and you will see

```
<form method="get" action="\">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how does the browser and HTML page know where to submit it? The button simply triggers a *submit* event, which is not defined on the page. Where is this event defined? How does the browser know it?

Comment: the action parameter tells the browser where to send the request.  
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: Ok, I got it! The form is submitted to index.php right? (because of action="/")

Answer (score 1):

It is a basic form submission via:

```
<form method="get" action="/">
```

Passing in the `find` input data. So essentially when you type the word *something* into the text box and click translate, the client is requesting a result from this address:

```
http://maduraonline.com/?find=something
```

Answer (score 1):

A little complement to the already posted answers.

The actual request is

```
http://maduraonline.com/index.php?find=something
```

But we see

```
http://maduraonline.com/?find=kk
```

mod_rewrite on the server takes care of redirecting the request for the root on the server to the default file, in this case, index.php, which in turn, is who does the work and calls whatever is necessary to make the translation.